# Train and test score - overfitting?

Tags: python, cross-validation, scikit-learn, train, tuning

I have hourly time series data with a range of two years. I want to test my model when predicting my target variable (continuous) for a specific week. I'm doing the following:

1. Splitting my data into training and test.
   (training data is all of the data before the week I want to predict)
   (testing data is the week I want to predict)
2. I'm using GridSearchCV to find parameters with Cross-Validation (it splits the training data into combinations of training and validation data with CV).
3. After I have the best parameters, I train my model with the training data (all of the data before the week I want to predict).
4. Then I finally predict the final week (X_test)

I'm getting good results, but how can I check for overfitting?

After step 2, I've plotted the cv_results_['mean_train_score'] and cv_results_['mean_test_score'] from the GridSearchCV and got the following:

**(The 'test' in the plot is refering to the validation datas in the cross validation)**

[image]

Does this indicate overfitting? If it does, how does it happen since my test data (the week I predict later) is not even included in the training/cross-validation phase and how can I prevent it? I think the test/validation value is way lower than the training value because this is a time series and when we are doing cross-validation (splitting data in blocks), sometimes we are predicting the beginning (first days/months) with later data which probably affects the result.

**Edit**:
The plot I display here is BEFORE predicting the test week. That plot is obtained after GridSearchCV. When I predict my X_test (unseen week) I get a value of really low value of MAPE, which is very good. Does this discard overfitting?

AFTER predicting my week I've got the following:

```
from slearn import metrics
print(metrics.r2_score(y_train,model.predict(X_train)))
print(metrics.r2_score(y_test,model.predict(X_test)))

0.9693362391994333 #TRAIN
0.9558915555507633 #TEST
```

Does this mean anything?

Comment: Your chart does suggest overfitting because the train scores are so much better than the test scores, but it may or may not be a bad thing: we cannot tell from this information whether less fitting might have produced better predictions for out-of-sample predictions

Comment: @Henry That test score is actually the validation score because that is made after GridSearchCV and BEFORE predicting the week